# How can I display structured text?

Tags: iphone, xml, ipad, ios

I have some text that I need to load from an XML file. The idea is to be able to make the text interactive. I should be able to tell when a user taps a piece of the text, like in the WordWeb app. I know this seems to be the kind of job that a UIWebView is for but I want to avoid generating HTML and implementing handlers for the hrefs. I hope that made any sense.

Another way could be using a UITableView with UITextViews or UILabels as content views for the cells. However, I couldn't find out how we can customize the appearance of the table view, add a border to the view for example.

The end result expected is a view that looks like a page from a book but pieces of the displayed text can be tapped and bookmarked etc.

Am I even thinking in the right direction?

Comment: This is really going to depend on how dynamic the XML is going to be. If you are loading the stuff from all sorts of random places, HTML is going to be the only sane way to do it. If it's only a few files you can parse the XML into various UI elements like UITextViews.

Comment: @Aurum Aquila It really is only a few XML files and I only load a list of items from the leaf nodes. Also, the XML is static. I load it from the disk.

Comment: Man... If you were developing this for Windows Phone, a List View would have been the answer. But there's no equivalent for iPhone. Your best bet is a UITableView that you can drill down into. I know there's a way to bind the data to XML or Core Data so you don't have to do much at all, but I can't find any of the tutorials right now...

Comment: Thanks, I managed it with a UITableView and a few customizations to the tableView and the cells. Eventually, I'll use a custom content view for the cells, there's even a background view for table views. The outcome till now looks promising.

Comment: Reg. Windows Phone, so is the SDK really cool? I can't wait to jump on that bandwagon too! Maybe learn some F# along the way!